# How to add a HTTPS inbound rule to a security group on an Amazon AWS EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I've created an AWS EC2 instance. What I'm trying to do is to add an inbound rule for the corresponding security group to the instance. The type of connection I wish the firewall to allow is HTTPS on port 443.

Every time I save it though, it changes to a Custom TCP Rule on port 443. Does anyone know why this happens and how may I allow a HTTPS connection to the instance?

Answer (score 0):

That is the way to configure it. Try to make a telnet connection towards the Instance using port 443 and it should be working.

Comment: i've tried connecting to the port and it doesn't seem to be responding

Comment: Is your EC2 Instance in the default VPC or in a custom VPC? In what subnet? From where are you testing the connection?

Answer (score 0):

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/connect-http-https-ec2/

Also see that your Network ACL is allowing https..
Send the screen shot of your inbound traffic rules

Comment: https://ibb.co/j9ZAfH these are the rules. How can i check if Network ACL is allowing https?